# GridView + System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid object name 'List'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a Problem...

I want to show my "*Automatically Created*" Table in my Form2...

I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid object name 'List'.......

but only for the "Automatically (`List`) created Table", the "Manually (`List1`) created Table" works fine in Form2...

idk why isnt working for the Automatically created Table...

I use this code for show the Table (works for `List1`, but not for `List`) ->

```cs
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeesListDataGridView.DataSource = GetEmployeesList();
    }

    private DataTable GetEmployeesList()
    {
        DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.ConsoleApp7ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [List]", con))// List1 for Testing...
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dtEmployees.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        return dtEmployees;
    }
```

Here i create a Table Automatically in my Application with (List)
---->

```
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List]("
                            + "[IDNumbers] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,"
                            + "[Numbers] DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,"
                            + "CONSTRAINT [PK_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDNumbers] ASC))", connection);
```

The Created Table looks in the ServerExplorer so ->

//Created Automatically, not working in GridView

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List] (
    [IDNumbers] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Numbers]   DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDNumbers] ASC)
);
```

So... After i created manually a Test Table (`List1`) its works to Show my Database in GridView.. ->

//Created Manually

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List1] (
    [IDNumbers] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Numbers]   DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_List1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDNumbers] ASC)
);
```

//Edit, Connection String

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ConsoleApp7.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

//Edit, Creating Database

```
        // Create New Database
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Delete the full Table and Create a new Table?", "Delete Table, and Create a new Table!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
         Task t5 = new Task(CreateNewDatabase); Task.Run(() => CreateNewDatabase());
        }
        else
        {   
        }
    }


        private async void CreateNewDatabase()
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string tableToDelete = "List";   //table name

            bool tableExists = false;
            DataTable dt = connection.GetSchema("tables");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() == tableToDelete)
                {
                    tableExists = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            if (tableExists)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new  SqlCommand(string.Format("DROP TABLE {0}", tableToDelete), connection))
                {
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
            {
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List]("
                            + "[IDNumbers] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,"
                            + "[Numbers] DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,"
                            + "CONSTRAINT [PK_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDNumbers] ASC))", connection);
                    {
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        AppendTextBox("Full Clear Database Table created.");
                        connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: when do you create List table? before GetEmployeesList() function or after GetEmployeesList() function? can I see whole code?

Comment: @EvaLai I have two buttons atm. in my Application, Button 1 Start a Task thats creating a new Table, the second button open a new form and show the GridView (not in a new task)

Comment: Did it create new table successfully after clicking Button 1?

Comment: The error message of "Invalid object name 'List'" shows that it can't find List table, there is no List table.

Comment: @EvaLai Yes, i know, that means "Invalid object name 'List'" says the table is not here, but the strange thing is, the table exist and is created by my "Automatically Creating Code".... i really must know why the "manually table" works, and the "Automatically table" not... D;

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. I don't understand what you mean by creating table automatically. And why do you have code to create a table in your database on form load? That seems absurd. What happens the second time your form loads?

Comment: well, I have no idea. I tried what you said, create Button 1 for creating table and create Button 2 for selecting new table. It worked fine....hope you can find the one help you

Comment: @SeanLange Why make this Question no sense? I mean, with creating a table, i click on a button, and then the application create for me a table.  In Form1 i have 2 Buttons, one for Creating a Table, and one for open Form 2 that show me the GridView with created Table. Same result, after restart my application :/

Comment: @EvaLai Thx anyway :)

Comment: @Deparli if you ran the code, and got an invalid object name error, check the table if exists in your database, if is it there, then hit (ctrl + shift+r) on your SSMS to refresh IntelliSense then try your code again, it should give you an error telling you that the table exists. If it does, drop the table do refresh cache again, and go back and try your code again, this should fix it if is it the reason.

Comment: Why are you creating a table from a button click? What happens when you click it a second time? This is a very strange thing to do in a program.

Comment: @Deparli if the issue still exists, please update your post with connectionString (if there is a username and password remove them).

Comment: @iSR5 Yep, Issue still exist... I added the ConnectionString.. But it make 0 Sense... Manually Created Table works fine, but the Created Table from the Button works not to show, but the table is created and exist and have the correct name... well... its not easy for a newcomer ;/

Comment: I agree this is a very odd question. Tables are usually persisted in the database, not created by a button push in an application. We are having trouble helping you because we don't understand your use case, and you haven't included the code that creates the table.

Comment: @Deparli add this `Initial Catalog= DatabaseName;` change DatabaseName to the one you're working on. Do clean and build your solution. Then debug again.

Comment: @JacobH I added the Code, how i create a Table, hope this helps..

Comment: @Deparli add it in your connectionString after `ConsoleApp7.mdf;`

Comment: @iSR5 Initial Catalog=...; Too not working, get still the Issue "Invalid object name..."

Comment: @Deparli in your `CreateNewDatabase()`  you need to rewrite it as it has some syntax error. check the parentheses before SqlCommand (one parentheses ) and after connection.Close();(two closing parentheses) . they need to be removed. Also, no need for connection.Close() inside using(sqlConnection) just an connection.Open is enough, and the connection will be disposed at the end of using.

Comment: @Deparli fix CreateNewDatabase() first, and then check

Comment: @Deparli also one parentheses above `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()` that need to be removed.

Comment: @iSR5 thank you for the help and tipps, i accepted the code snippet from rasti, need to learn more to write a better"working" code ;D :) first thing, i rewrite the whole code ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm not misunderstanding your question 
you code will work in this way

```
private DataTable GetEmployeesList()
    {
        DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=yourconnectin;Initial Catalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            cn.Open();

            string createTable = "IF OBJECT_ID('List') IS  NULL Begin " +
               "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[List]("+
                      " [IDNumbers] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,"+
                        "[Numbers] DECIMAL(18, 8) NULL," +
                        "  CONSTRAINT[PK_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([IDNumbers] ASC))" +
                 "END";

            using (SqlCommand cmddd = new SqlCommand(createTable, cn))
            {
                cmddd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM List", cn))// List1 for Testing...
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dtEmployees.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        return dtEmployees;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you... I see, i must learn so much more, to write a "working" Code... Thanks for the Code snippet :)